# Commutative law in matrix and algebraic identities

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, commutative-algebra

We know that
if two matrices are commutative, then any algebraic identity holds for two matrices.

What about inverse of this theorem? Can we conclude that the two matrices are commutative, if a specific algebraic identity holds?

$(A+B)^3=A^3+B^3+3A^2B+3AB^2$ => $AB=BA$